# R - Apply a function based on logical vector

Tags: r

I have the following code, but it throws the following error:

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Obviously this means that I am misusing the `if (condition) {action}` construction, so I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this:

```
if (grepl("Spring", data$Survey)) {data["Season"] <- "Spring"}
if (grepl("Summer", data$Survey)) {data["Season"] <- "Summer"}
if (grepl("Fall", data$Survey)) {data["Season"] <- "Fall"}
```

Basically, I would like to input a logical vector, and for every `TRUE`, apply a function to a data set of the same length (in this case, assigning a string value to that row of a dataframe).

Comment: `dplyr::mutate_if` might be what you are looking for

Comment: `data["Season"] <- ifelse (grepl("Spring", data$Survey)) , "Spring", ifelse (grepl("Summer", data$Survey)) , "Summer", ifelse (grepl("Fall", data$Survey)) , "Fall")))`

Comment: @HubertL, that seems to along the lines of what I need. Can you post it as an answer and explain it a bit? I'm not so sure how you're trying to do it in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` which is vectorial instead of `if`:

```
data$Season <- ifelse(grepl("Spring", data$Survey), 
                         "Spring", 
                         ifelse(grepl("Summer", data$Survey), 
                                "Summer",  
                                ifelse(grepl("Fall", data$Survey), 
                                       "Fall",
                                       "Winter")))
```

For each element of `data$Survey` : First `ifelse` will check if it contains "Spring" , then assign it to the corresponding item in `data$Season`, otherwise second ifelse will check if it contains "Summer"...

Comment: You seem to have misplaced some parentheses. Did you mean the following? `data["Season"] <- ifelse(grepl("Spring", data$Survey), "Spring", ifelse(grepl("Summer", data$Survey), "Summer", ifelse(grepl("Fall", data$Survey), "Fall", "Other")))`

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I need, and without any external packages. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could do this in one step using *e.g.* `stringr::str_extract`. It will return `<NA>` if there is no match.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- data.frame(Survey = sample(c("it's Spring yay",
                                     "it's Summer yay",
                                     "it's Fall yay"),
                            20, replace = TRUE))

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(Season = str_extract(Survey, "(Spring|Summer|Fall)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` to do this

```
data$Season <-  regmatches(data$Survey, regexpr("\\b(Spring|Survey|Fall)\\b", data$Survey))
data$Season
#[1] "Spring" "Spring" "Fall"   "Fall"   "Spring" "Spring" "Fall"   "Spring" "Fall"   "Spring" "Spring"
#[12] "Fall"   "Spring" "Fall"
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(Survey = sample(c("it's Spring yay",
                                 "it's Summer yay",
                                 "it's Fall yay"),
                        20, replace = TRUE))
```